# Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, program-entry-point

I have problem running the following code, it says `Error: Could not find or load main class` but i clearly have a main in the code...

```
    package abc;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

// As its name implies, this is what is driving the program, asking for input, giving output, etc.
public class driver
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException // a main that throws an exception... hmmm... yes it's odd, but apparently not illegal
    {
        ....}

    private static void processTransaction(String trans, Customer[] customers) throws IOException // this is the function that processes the given transaction
    {
        ...
}

// An object representing a person who may have one or more bank accounts
class Customer
{
    ...
}

class BankAccount 
{
    ...
}

class CheckingAccount extends BankAccount // extends BankAccount with added functionality
{
    ...
}

class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount // extends BankAccount with added functionality
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your sscce is not quite short :)

Comment: i'm leaving this in a comment instead of an answer because this is wild guessing, but maybe your compiler is looking for `main` the class rather than `main` the method, or maybe it it looking for a `main` that does not throw an `IOException`

Comment: In fact the problem is not in the SSCCE that you posted. Its something else.

Comment: You can't have a package called `default`, it won't compile.

Comment: @RohitJain what could it be?

Comment: @SamIam.. I bet, you saved yourself so much reputation by not posting it as answer.

Comment: @user133466.. What is the name of your compilation unit? Is it `driver`? And P.S, name your class starting with upper case letters please.

Comment: It runs in my IDE, just fine (without the `package default;`) Perhaps you have not set your class path correctly.

Comment: @RohitJain  Well, I would normally expect the compiler to find the `main` method, but the error said it didn't, thus the guessing

Comment: @SamIam.. Hmm. That was a wild guess though. ;)

Comment: Just a note: why use `JInputDialog` for yes no questions when you could use `JConfirmDialog` which is designed for yes no questions ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try giving your class access specifier to public

```
public class driver
```

Comment: a new error arises: The public type driver must be defined in its own file...

Comment: @user133466.. There you go. That was the problem. Change your file name to `driver.java`

Comment: @user133466.. Good. Now you can accept this answer. Of course after 6 minutes from now.